# Angular 5 - Why can't I see all my TypeScript models in Chrome's debugger?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, angular-cli

I'm trying to debug my Angular 5 app in Chrome.

I've created it using *ng cli*, and I'm running it using *ng serve*.

My *models* folder has 7 TypeScript files / classes and a sub-folder containing 4 files / classes, but in Chrome's Developer Tools I only see a total of 3 files.

[image]

Any ideas why?

**Note**: I will provide more information as required... As an Angular beginner, I just don't know what other information you would need to answer this, so feel free to ask.

Comment: Did you try a Ctrl + F5 ? Server restart ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun Yes, thanks.  I've tried Ctrl + F5.  I've also used ng build and ran the dist files on a different server.  Same result.

Comment: I have found that the best way to navigate angular src in the browser is by using the **debugger;**  type that anywhere in your code and the browsers will stop at that point and show the src tree and files

Comment: To open a file in the chrome dev tools use `Ctrl + P` shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Angular compiles it will not load models that are not being used. My bet is that you are seeing those three models, because you have declared them somewhere in your code, but not the other models that aren't being displayed.

This can be quickly verified if in one of your components you just import your models

```
import { SomeModel } from './someModel';
```

and create a new instance of it

```
public something= new SomeModel(1,'','');
```

You should then see all you model files displayed in your sources directory.